# Customizing phpMyAdmin interface

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a database created using phpMyAdmin and would like to upload a theme i downloaded from the internet but can't find the directory where i should upload the theme to.

The version im using is 4.8 installed using cPanel hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Themes for phpMyAdmin are kept in the `themes` folder. Since you're using cPanel, I'm not certain if they move the folder location, but a good place to start would be by finding the packaged themes that are included with the main download.

A quick Google search suggests one possible install location could be `/usr/local/cpanel/base`, but that's just a guess. You may have to use your file manager to do a file level search for a folder called `pmahomme`, that will exist in the phpMyAdmin theme folder. Once you find the folder that's in, you can put your downloaded theme in the same folder.

Themes are automatically detected, but remember that you have to download a theme that matches the phpMyAdmin version you have (or edit the `theme.json` file to change the supported version), otherwise it won't show up in the theme dropdown.